# I want to search and find gigs with the help of its fields and its multiple association tables fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

Gig table:
[image]
Gig table has association with Business, GigType and GigDetails table.I want to get Gigs by any column value of Business or GigType or GigDetails table

Business Table:
[image]

GigType Table:
[image]

GigDetails Table:
[image]

Comment: Can you post tables as text or create a https://dbfiddle.uk/; IT will be easy to understand problem.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand your problem, but i asume you want to be able to get all rows returned from the GIGs table ONLY by inserting a where clause on any of the corresponding values of any if the subtables?

If so, then this can easily be done by generating a left join between the main gigs table and all other tables which just returns the gigs-table columns, and then filter with a where clause on the specific columns of the other tables.

For example, the main SQL would then be:

```
Select g.* from Gigs g 
left join Business b on g.business_id = b.id
left join GigType gt on g.type = gt.id
left join GigDetails gd on g.details = gd.id
```

Then you can add a where clause to return only those gigs which have any of the afformentioned field values

```
Select g.* from Gigs g 
left join Business b on g.business_id = b.id
left join GigType gt on g.type = gt.id
left join GigDetails gd on g.details = gd.id
where gt.qualifications = 'Hotel Bookkeeping' -- This could be replaced with any column filter
```

If your goal was to just give a value like 'Hotel Bookkeeping' without telling in which column it should be and then getting the right gig retrieved, then you can use a reversed in statement in the where, to search not for a couple of values in a column, but to search for 1 value in a couple of columns:

```
Select g.* from Gigs g 
left join Business b on g.business_id = b.id
left join GigType gt on g.type = gt.id
left join GigDetails gd on g.details = gd.id
where 'Hotel Bookkeeping' in (g.id, g.business_id, g.title, g.description, g.type, g.thumbnail, b.brandname, b."ABN", gt.qualifications)
-- Just replace the string for the keyword you want to search for, and add the columns to look into in between the braces
```